# Issue with app build using Gulp and gulp-load-plugins

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, gulp-load-plugins

I have an issue with building of my project. I started to use gulp-load-plugins on my project to speedup Gulp.

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Project",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "description": "Project",
  "author": "DOBRO GROUP",
  "scripts": {
    "watch-frontend": "gulp watch:front",
    "watch-backend": "gulp watch:back",
    "build": "gulp build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "bootstrap-sass": "^3.3.7",
    "browser-sync": "^2.18.13",
    "del": "^3.0.0",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "^4.0.0",
    "gulp-cache": "^0.4.6",
    "gulp-clean": "^0.3.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-consolidate": "^0.2.0",
    "gulp-file-copy": "0.0.1",
    "gulp-iconfont": "^9.0.0",
    "gulp-iconfont-css": "^2.1.0",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^3.3.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "^1.5.0",
    "gulp-plumber": "^1.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "^1.2.2",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "^2.6.0",
    "gulp-uglifyjs": "^0.6.2",
    "gulp-watch": "^4.3.11",
    "npm-clean": "^1.0.3",
    "path": "^0.12.7",
    "pump": "^1.0.2",
    "run-sequence": "^2.1.0",
    "underscore": "^1.8.3"
  }
}
```

This is my gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';

var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({
        pattern: '*'
    });

var fsys = require('./settings.json');

function getTask(task) {
    return require('./gulp-tasks/' + task)(gulp, plugins);
}
gulp.task('cache', getTask('cache'));
gulp.task('clean', getTask('clean'));
gulp.task('sass:front', getTask('sass-front'));
gulp.task('sass:back', getTask('sass-back'));
gulp.task('browser-sync', getTask('browser-sync'));
gulp.task('js:front', getTask('js-front'));
gulp.task('js:back', getTask('js-back'));
gulp.task('font:gen:front', getTask('font-gen-front'));
gulp.task('font:copy:front', function () {
    return gulp.src(fsys.path.frontend.fonts.source + '**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(fsys.path.frontend.fonts.dest));
});
gulp.task('font:copy:back', function () {
    return gulp.src(fsys.path.backend.font.source + '**/*/')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(fsys.path.backend.font.dest));
});
gulp.task('img:copy:front', function () {
    return gulp.src(fsys.path.frontend.img.source + '**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(fsys.path.frontend.img.dest))
});
gulp.task('img:copy:back', function () {
    return gulp.src(fsys.path.backend.img.source + '**/*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(fsys.path.backend.img.dest))
});



gulp.task('build', getTask('build'));
```

At first build it seems there is no any problems. But if I run build task again I get errors like that:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, chmod

```
'D:\laragon\www\design\public\assets\frontend\fonts\AvantGardeCTT.eot'
    at Error (native)
```

This error occures on file copy tasks. Here is the example of this kind of task:

```
gulp.task('font:copy:front', function () {
    return gulp.src(fsys.path.frontend.fonts.source + '**/*.*')
        .pipe(gulp.dest(fsys.path.frontend.fonts.dest));
});
```

I'm looking throw all google and try to find an answer. But with no result.

Comment: `chmod` is a UNIX command to change file permissions. As I can see you are running this on windows. Looks like one of the scripts was written to be run on UNIX-like (Linux or MacOS) systems only or it has a bug not checking on which OS it runs.

Comment: I create a copy tasks which don't use any plugin. So I don't have any idea why it can create a bug. By the way I'm using Win10 on my side.

Comment: I meant that gulp may have a bug when it does not check on which system it runs before it tries to do `chmod`. Is it Win10 with the Ubuntu subsystem? I'm not sure how it works there...

Comment: Is there any solution?